# C sockets first two characters of value are missing when printed

Tags: c, sockets, recv

Hi everyone i am trying to print a string that has been sent from a server to a client, but when i do, it is missing the first two characters. i have assigned enough memory to the character array so i am not sure what is wrong here.

client code to receive:

```
char buffer[62]; // I/O buffer 
    char phrase[100];
    char reversed[20];
    int i,m; 
    /* Receive up to the buffer size (minus 1 to leave space for
     a null terminator) bytes from the sender */
    numBytes = recv(sock, buffer, 62, 0); //recv by number of bytes of greeting string (which is 60 bytes)
    if (numBytes < 0)
      DieWithSystemMessage("recv() failed");
    else if (numBytes == 0)
      DieWithUserMessage("recv()", "connection closed prematurely");
    totalBytesRcvd += numBytes; // Keep tally of total bytes
    buffer[numBytes] = '\0';    // Terminate the string!
    printf("Received:%s ", buffer);     // Setup to print the echoed string
    numBytes = recv(sock, phrase,100, 0); //set numbytes to amount 
    if (numBytes < 0)
      DieWithSystemMessage("recv() failed");
    else if (numBytes == 0)
      DieWithUserMessage("recv()", "connection closed prematurely");
    totalBytesRcvd += numBytes; // Keep tally of total bytes
    phrase[numBytes] = '\0';    // Terminate the string!
    printf("\nShort phrase from server: %s\n",phrase);
    m = strlen(phrase); //get length of phrase
    for(i=m-1; i>=0; i--){
     sprintf(reversed,"%c",phrase[i]);
      printf("%s",reversed);
```

The "short phrase from server" is printing twork instead of Network

server code that sends values:

```
void HandleTCPClient(int clntSocket) {
  char buffer[BUFSIZE]; // Buffer for echo string
  char clientIP[10];
  char clientPort[10];
  char greeting[60];
  char shortPhrase[10] = "Network";
  char reversed[10];
  // Receive message from client 39
  ssize_t numBytesRcvd = recv(clntSocket, buffer, 39, 0);
  if (numBytesRcvd < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("recv() failed");
    printf("first recv: %s", buffer);
   //recv client ip and assign to variable to hold
    recv(clntSocket,clientIP,10,0);
    printf("clientIP : %s\n" ,clientIP);
//recv client port and assign to variable to hold
    recv(clntSocket,clientPort,10,0);
    printf("client port : %s\n" ,clientPort);



//create greeting string to send to client
sprintf(greeting,"%s-%s Welcome to the netsvr netserver!",clientIP,clientPort); //assign myPort integer to char so we can send it

//recv client port and assign to variable to hold
   ssize_t numBytesSent = send(clntSocket, greeting, 60, 0);
    send(clntSocket,shortPhrase,10,0);

  recv(clntSocket,reversed,10,0);
  printf("reversed phrase : %s\n" ,reversed);
  // Send greeting string and receive again until end of stream
  while (numBytesRcvd > 0) { // 0 indicates end of stream
    // Echo message back to client
    // See if there is more data to receive
    numBytesRcvd = recv(clntSocket, buffer, 20, 0);
    if (numBytesRcvd < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("recv() failed");


  }

close(clntSocket); // Close client socket
}
```

Comment: Note that in the client you ask `recv` to read up to 62 bytes. If you do receive that then `numBytes` will be equal to `62` and when do `buffer[numBytes] = '\0'` you will be writing out of bounds. Receive one less than the size of the buffer.

Comment: Are you using a stream or datagram socket?

Comment: i am using TCP with stream socket, sir

Comment: thanks for your comment @Someprogrammerdude i have done what you have suggested and lowered each recv by 1 and now the "short phrase" is printing etwork so there is still one character missing, i think i am on the right track with this!

Comment: You should look for the N in the bytes read by the first recv.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the code.  And strongly suggest formatting the posted code for ease of readability

Comment: the posted code contains lots of 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest giving those magic numbers meaningful names (via an `enum` statement or `#define` statements) then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line

Comment: I only just got back on here, sorry for the delay. I managed to figure out my issue, after reading through my code a few times I found that I was sending more bytes than what I was receiving, also I stupidly assigned values way to high for what I was actually sending. Thanks for the constructive feedback, I will take that on board for when I comment again in the future